# Multiple meta query from array

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, array

I need to do multiple meta query from my array. I have something like this:

```
$search_term[] = array(
  'key' => '_cmb_listing_status',
  'value' => 'Active',
  'compare' => '='
);
foreach ( $refine_property_type as $search_value ) {
    $search_term[] =
            array(
                'key' => '_cmb_property_type',
                'value' => $search_value,
                'compare' => '='
            );
}
```

And that gives output like this:

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [key] => _cmb_listing_status
        [value] => Active
        [compare] => =
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [key] => _cmb_property_type
        [value] => House
        [compare] => =
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [key] => _cmb_property_type
        [value] => Office
        [compare] => =
    )
)
```

I am doing meta query in worpdress with this code:

```
$args = array(
'paged' => $paged,
'post_type' => 'property',
'posts_per_page' => 5,
'meta_key' => '_cmb_listing_featured',
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'DESC',
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
     $search_term
    )
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

And it just won't work ? Can anyone help me out to figure this out? I think it's because the multidimensional array is being passed into the query, but I am not sure how to "flatten" it inside WP_Query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$search_term` is already an array of an array. When you eventually add that to your `meta_query`, you get an array of an array of an array, which will not work

You are using `AND` as your `relation` operator which is the default for a multi-array `meta_query`. I would suggest that you drop that, and then simply just feed `$search_term` directly to your `meta_query`. No arrays.

Example

```
'meta_query' => $search_term,
```

Comment: And is there a way to change relation operator to "OR" ?

Comment: Yes. You need to add that to your `$search_term` array. I'm thinking like using `array_unshift` to add that key/value pair to the array. `relation` would be your key while `OR` will be the value.

Comment: Thanks Pieter, after some goggling I realized that I'll have to mix "AND" and "OR" relation operators and since that's not possible I'll write my own SQL queries. Thanks for the help !

Comment: My pleasure, and good luck with your project. :-)